# Statistics program from an array

Tags: java

I need to create a program that outputs the min, max, average, population standard deviation and sample standard deviation from array values entered by the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



    System.out.println("How many of the type double do you want to store"
            + " in your array?: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    double[] arrayofvals = new double[number];
    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter value " + (i+1) + " : ");
            arrayofvals[i] = input.nextDouble();


    }
     {


    }

    System.out.print("----------------------------------------\nHere are "
            + "the stats for your values: \n------------------------------"
            + "----------");
    double max = getMax(arrayofvals);
    System.out.println("\nMaximum value is: " +max);

    double min = getMin(arrayofvals);
    System.out.println("\nMinimum value is: " + min);

    double average = getMean (arrayofvals);
    System.out.println("\nAverage of array values is: " + total);



}
public static double getMax(double[] arrayofvals){
    double maxValue = arrayofvals[0];
    for(int i=1;i < arrayofvals.length; i++){
        if(arrayofvals[i] > maxValue){
            maxValue = arrayofvals[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
public static double getMin(double[] arrayofvals){
    double minValue = arrayofvals[0];
    for(int i=1;i < arrayofvals.length; i++){
        if(arrayofvals[i] < minValue){
            minValue = arrayofvals[i];
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}

public static double getMean (double[] arrayofvals){
    double total = 0;

    double avgVal = arrayofvals[0];
for (int i =0; i< arrayofvals.length; i++){
total = total + arrayofvals[i];
    }
 double average = total / arrayofvals.length;
return avgVal;


}
```

}

I can't get past the average calculation because I keep getting a return of 0. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: For a start `System.out.println("\nAverage of array values is: " + average);` **not** `total`

Comment: Also returning the wrong value from `getMean()`.

Comment: Hint:: If you use an IDE like `Eclipse` then the `unused` variable `average` in `getMean` will be highlighted for you

Comment: You might want to look at using a debugger. This will help you step through your code and identify problems. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html They are often integrated with IDEs like IntelliJ - https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arrayofvals).summaryStatistics());`

Answer (score 0):

retutn  average , not avgVal;

```
public static double getMean (double[] arrayofvals){
    double total = 0;   
    for (int i =0; i< arrayofvals.length; i++){
       total = total + arrayofvals[i];
    }
    double average = total / arrayofvals.length;
    return average;
}
```

and in `main` print average instead of `total`

```
 double average = getMean (arrayofvals);
 System.out.println("\nAverage of array values is: " + average);// replaced total with average
```

Comment: and what have you achieved apart from re-iterating the  simple typos that have already been commented on?

Comment: @ScaryWombat you only talk about the print statement in main function. I point out the mistake in `getMean` function too. Read my answer again. and what is the reason on my every answer you are putting -1 ?

Comment: Not just talking about my comments but others as well.  BTW, not my `-1`, but I can if you want ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat i was writing the answer before the first comment. and after posting the answe, i seee that comments :) if you see error in my answer then sure put -1 otherwise +1 is a option too :-)